# Able to display images thorough Inspect Element –inspector but not sure where the img tag should be added in js file

Tags: javascript

Here I am doing some reverse engineering in node js and javascript, I am able to display the images through page inspector in div lines but, not sure where I should add image tag in javascript, I don’t have HTML page to change the dive lines, the data is getting passed through jquery and displayed using JSON 
Able to display images through Inspect Element –inspector:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://assets.ipapi.com/flags/us.svg" alt="Country Flag" width="12" height="12">
</div>
```

but not sure where I should be updating the same in which file. There is no HTML having div etc
Here are the further code lines from the inspector, thanks a lot

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to ask. What do you need to update and why? Are you writing a new version of the code? Are you asking how to create an image tag using JavaScript? Or how to parse the HTML to look for these tags using code? You haven't explained your situation very well, unfortunately. Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am attempting to modify java script code for an application, here data getting injected through jQuery with random function, then the JSON data is parsed and getting displayed on the page. Here when I attempt to pass the http url data then the webpage is displaying complete passed http url but, this is not getting converted to image on the page. however when I attempted through inspect element by updating the same line as above, then I am able to see the image

Comment: you'll have to show us the code you are using to try and do this process, we can't really fix any issues with code if we can't see it. Thanks.

Comment: When I pass the value
var getv=`<img src='http://assets.ipapi.com/flags/us.svg' alt='Country Flag' width='12' height='12'></img>`;
I see the output on page as: <img src='http://assets.ipapi.com/flags/us.svg' alt='Country Flag' width='12' height='12'></img>
Oninspect:
Its converting to  &lg, &gt as below 
<div class="item">&lt;img src='http://assets.ipapi.com/flags/us.svg' alt='Country Flag' width='12' height='12'&gt;&lt;/img&gt;</div>
But, if I edit the above code as:
<div class="item"><img src='http://assets.ipapi.com/flags/us.svg' alt='Country Flag' width='12' height='12'></img></div>

Comment: i.e. converting back to < and > I see the expected results. 
All your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried with escape characters, npm install prototype,  npm install --save unescape, npm install base64-img –save, npm install --save-dev javascript-obfuscator BUT no luck

Comment: Please include code in your question by using the "edit" button, then you can format it and make it readable. Thanks